# How can I control and reduce memory used by FFmpeg in AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ffmpeg, aws-lambda, video-processing

I set up AWS Lambda (Python 3.8) with FFmpeg as a layer to repackage .mov files to HLS.
Here's the command which I use to repackage clips:

`/opt/ffmpeg -i file_name.mov -codec: copy -start_number 1 -hls_time 10 -hls_playlist_type vod -hls_list_size 0 -f hls -master_pl_name master_name.m3u8 master.m3u8`

Command is then being run by using:

`subprocess.run(ffmpeg_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, preexec_fn=setlimits)`

Everything is working fine for smaller files (e.g. 5GB) but I also need it to work for files of size up to 15GB.
That's when Lambda is time outing as it runs out of the memory which I set to maximum 10GB and FFmpeg is using all of it to repackage large clip.

I was trying to limit FFmpeg memory usage by using Python Resource module (as you can see by `preexec_fn`)
Here's the function:

```
def setlimits():
    resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_AS, (1048576, 1048576))
```

But it didn't help and resulted in FFmpeg not being run at all...
Is there a way to control FFmpeg memory usage? Or maybe I can upgrade my FFmpeg command to be less memory consuming?
The main point of repackaging those .mov files is **not to** change their quality.